# Meaning of "seething breeding"?

Tags: meaning

I try to translate this phrase into another language, and I am confused. Is this an idiomatic expression which refers to enthusiasm or abundance? 
This is the name of a chapter in a book that I am working on: "The seething breeding glioma"

I also see these sentences when I google it:

> It's a seething breeding ground for art thieves
>
> Latin American countries as a seething breeding ground of violence
>   have been widespread

Comment: Have you tried to look up each word individually?

Comment: @simchona, yes I did! It seems to me that these words may have different meaning together! That the reason why I am asking about it. Is this an idiomatic phrase?

Comment: The name of the chapter you cite--are you reading it, or did you write it?

Comment: The author wrote it, and I am trying to translate it, so I did not write. (I edited my question, sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Seething breeding" is not an idiom, although you can find the two words together on occasion. I think the problem you may be having is in parsing the words next to *seething breeding*. In the two examples you cited, the noun is a *breeding ground*, and then that noun is in turn *seething*. To bracket it simply, it is:

[seething [breeding [ground]]]

A [breeding ground](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breeding+grounds) is:

> A place or set of circumstances that encourages the development of certain ideas or conditions

So a [seething](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/seething) breeding ground is a breeding ground which is in a state of excitement or agitation.

---

Now, I am not in the medical field so I am fairly uneducated in what a *glioma* is. Having looked it up, I am aware that it is a [type of tumor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glioma).  I believe that the same brackets can apply to help parse the phrase:

[seething [breeding [glioma]]]

That is, the *glioma* itself breeds (probably by spreading through the body, creating other tumors). So it is a *breeding glioma*. This "breeding glioma" is also in a state of agitation, or it is seething--thus, it is a *seething breeding glioma*.

Comment: @thank you, now I understand. At least, I know that I am not doing something wrong.